# Salesforce apex trigger duplicate id in list

Tags: list, triggers, duplicates, salesforce

In my order insert trigger, i need to update contact for the order information, I know there are duplicate records in the my contact list. so I use
Contact[] contactToUpdate = new List(new Set(contactList));
to remove the duplicates.

but I still receive the error message: duplicate in List.

any idea??

Thanks

Comment: Hi Lee, for want of a better place to tell you about this, we're having our first Melbourne Developers Group Meetup week after next - http://www.meetup.com/Melbourne-Salesforce-Platform-Developer-Users-Group/

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you very much for organizing such a event! I will definitely see you there. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are correct that a set contains unique elements, but the issue is that you're dealing with instances of contact: just because two instances refer to the same contact in the DB they are still different object instances in memory and therefore are unique, the upshot being you can have to entries in the set representing the same contact with the same id.

The easiest way around this would be to use a map of id to contact:

```
map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new map<id, Contact>();
```

For each order you process, you can use the contact lookup as a key to the map to reach the contact you want to update. At the end of your processing you can then update the contacts simply by calling:

```
update mapContacts.values();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I have another question: so when the record is recognized as an instance and when as a record ?

Comment: It's never recognised as a 'record' as such in code, it's always an instance of a class which represents a database object. If you did selected a contact from the database, stored it in a variable c, and then added c to the set twice it would only appear once as it is one instance.

Querying twice into two variables creates two different instances which could both be added.

Comment: Did anyone tell you that you are amazing? Thanks a lot.